# MySql database content viewer

Tags: mysql, database, erd

I'm seeking for a tool, that would allow me to view/test my data that's stored in my database. I need something similar that is offered in MS Access, where you can test your database thru table views which have relationships.
Basicly i need an ERD tool, which can dynamicly shows stored table data.

Comment: Off topic - Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with Mysqlworkbench

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/